# Alarm manager triggers continuously though time is different

Tags: android

I am trying to deliver pending intent to a service in onStartCommand(). But once alarm is set it is triggering continuously. I am setting two alarms one at 4 AM and one at 8 PM. I wanted to achieve logic such that, when intent for alarm at 4 AM is delivered then alarm for 8 PM should set and when intent for alarm at 8 PM is delivered then alarm for 4 AM should be set. But it is working unexpectedly. When 8 PM intent is delivered then in 4 seconds the intent for 4 AM is delivered which is again setting alarm for 8 PM and this cycle repeats.
Where I am making mistake? please guide me.

```
public class Alarmclass extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private String Stat;

private boolean GetTypeofAlarm() { 
    Log.e("Getting type", "Getting alarm types");
    boolean alarmtype = false;
    int hours;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if (hours <= 5) {
        alarmtype = false;
    } else if (hours >= 20) {
        alarmtype = false;
    } else if (hours >= 5 && hours <= 20)
        alarmtype = true;
    return alarmtype;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (!GetTypeofAlarm()) {
      StartLocAlarm();
    }else{
      StopLocAlarm();
    } 
  }

    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent.hasExtra("START")) {            

     if(intent.getStringExtra("START").equals("START_ALR")) {
           StopLocAlarm();
        }
     }else if(intent.hasExtra("STOP")){
        if(intent.getStringExtra("STOP").equals("STOP_ALR")) {
      StartLocAlarm();
     }
    }

   Intent Actint = new Intent(this, Startup_Activity.class);
    Actint.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2422, Actint, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Admin")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText(Stat)
            .setOngoing(true).build();
    startForeground(201, notification);

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void StartLocAlarm(){

    AlarmManager alrmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
    alrmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alarmclass.class);
    intent.putExtra("START", "START_ALR");
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);


    alrmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(),alarmIntent);
    Log.e("In onstart","Setting alarm at 5 AM");
    Stat = "Alarm set for 5 AM";

}

private void StopLocAlarm(){

    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Alarmclass.class);
    intent2.putExtra("STOP", "STOP_ALR");
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, intent2, 0);

    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
    Log.e("In onstart", "Setting alarm at 8 PM");
    Stat = "Alarm set for 8 PM";
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the 4am alarm on the same day that you are now. 4am should be set to the next day.. 
For example : today is wednesday, at 8pm the alarm is triggered. You next alarm should be set on thursday, at 4am.

Add a day to your calendar (this supports the end of the month as well, so thats all you need to do.

```
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //Adding 1 day
```

Comment: Its still cycling continuously.

Comment: i don't understand... do you want only when your user presses on the notification then set the next alarm ?

Comment: No I want the alarm to be set automatically without any user interaction.

Comment: so why isn't this good? when : 4am is called -> 8pm is called -> tomorrow 4am is called -> 8pm is called ... like so ?

Comment: yes the same I wanted to implement. but its not working like this, its just cycling continuously between 4 AM and 8 PM for every 4-5 Sec!

Comment: just a question : why not just do 2 alarm everyday, 1 set for 8pm and 1 for 4am ?

Comment: I have used as you suggested, now cycling is stopped. And setting alarms from the intent received was causing issue. Now I am thinking how should I set both the alarms. As both are setting in onCreate now so I have to start the service and then alarm will be set. Anyways I will try to look into it.